# Python OpenCV plot circles at a list of centre coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, plot, geometry

I have been able to generate a list of coordinates that i would like to use as the centres of mulltiple small circles that i would like to plot on an image.

I am able to plot circles at individual points but have not been able to find the correct syntax for plotting circles at all of the centres. The coordinates i wish to use for the centres are stored as follows, in an array named Points which has a shape :(11844, 2)

```
[[  5   5]
 [  5  10]
 [  5  15]
 ..., 
 [630 460]
 [630 465]
 [630 470]]
```

I am able to plot an individual circle by using the following code:

```
cv2.circle(frame1,(5,5),1,(0,0,255))
```

I have tried to plot all points by using :

```
cv2.circle(frame1,Points[:,:],1,(0,0,255))
```

This gives back this error though:

```
cv2.circle(frame1,Points[:,:],1,(0,0,255))
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Am i supposed to be using a loop to step through all the points and plot them one by one? If so which loop should I use? Or is there something simple that i am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find the answer with help from Joel using the following code:

```
    for point in Points:
        cv2.circle(frame1,tuple(point),1,(0,0,255))
```

Comment: you should mark this as an answer by ticking the green mark next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work:

```
for point in Points:
    cv2.circle(frame1, point, 1,(0,0,255))
```

Comment: Seems like this could get unnecessarily slow for a lot of points.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
for point in Points:
    cv2.circle(frame1, points, 1,(0,0,255))
```

Comment: I tried it as you suggested using both 'point' and 'Points' inside the circles function, I get the same error for both however: 'SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple'